# Merging objects in PHP based on a property

Tags: php, arrays, object, merge

What I am originally trying to do is merge two objects

I have one object like this

```
{#23 ▼
  +"Name": "Consultation"
  +"ServiceId": "1024"
  +"Price": ".00"
}
```

Another object

```
{#362 ▼
  +"StartTime": "9:15AM"
  +"ServiceId": "1024"
}
```

I am looking for a way to merge these two objects based on it's `ServiceId`, so I get a single object like this

```
   {#1 ▼
      +"Name": "Consultation"
      +"ServiceId": "1024"
      +"Price": ".00"
      +"StartTime": "9:15AM"
     }
```

Of course, if the ServiceId between the two objects do not match, it should not merge.

Any ideas on how to solve the error?

Comment: What class are your objects?

Comment: @bishop These objects are not instantiated from a class, these are made using json_decode() function.

Comment: Instead use `json_decode($your_json,true)` and then try `array_merge`

Comment: You have a arrays of multiple objects or just one object in each array?

Comment: There are arrays of multiple objects ,but I am looping through it to get one object and trying to compare them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be two parts to your question. The first part is how to merge the output of two objects returned by `json_decode`. The second part is how to merge them only if the ServiceId match.

---

**Part 1**

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) produces, by default, objects of class `\StdClass`. If you want merge two `\StdClass` objects into a third `\StdClass` object, you need some judicious casting:

```
$a = json_decode('{"Name":"Consultation", "ServiceId":"1024", "Price":".00"}');
$b = json_decode('{"StartTime": "9:15AM", "ServiceId": "1024"}');
$c = (object)array_merge((array)$a, (array)$b);
var_dump($c);
```

Here, `$a` and `$b` are `\StdClass` objects. Cast them to `array`, merge, then cast them back to `\StdClass`.

That's a bit of a round-about way to go. So, you can benefit from working with these as arrays from the get-go. `json_decode` takes an optional second argument, which instructs it to return an array:

```
$a = json_decode('{"Name":"Consultation", "ServiceId":"1024", "Price":".00"}', true);
$b = json_decode('{"StartTime": "9:15AM", "ServiceId": "1024"}', true);
$c = array_merge($a, $b);
var_dump($c);
```

This works in arrays the whole time. If you later want `$c` to be a `\StdClass` object, you can cast it using `$c = (object)$c;` as was done in the first example.

[See these live on 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/dvNB2)

---

**Part 2**

Presumably, you're going to need some logic that iterates or otherwise pairs these objects together. You don't mention the source, but the logic will look something like this:

```
if ($a->ServiceId == $b->ServiceId) {
    $c = (object)array_merge((array)$a, (array)$b)
}
```

If you have a list of objects, and you want to merge them all together, you can use the combinatoric array walk behavior of [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
$merged = [];
usort($objects, function ($a, $b) use ($merged) {
    $comp = strcmp($a->ServiceId, $b->ServiceId);
    if (0 === $comp) {
        $merged[] = (object)array_merge((array)$a, (array)$b)
    }
    return $comp;
});
var_dump($merged);
```

This iterates through your list of objects, comparing each. If the `ServiceId` match, then it merges the two objects and adds it to a list of merged. This will happen for as many objects that share `ServiceId` as you have in your list.

Comment: Thank you, but this actually does not work it just merges two objects irrespective of property, and it's NOT based on ServiceId

Comment: Because you are asking a two part question, yet giving only enough information for one part.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, actually the main functionality I am trying to find is to pair two objects together based on a property (which is the main title of my question)

Comment: Well, give this update a whirl. If it doesn't work, post more information about your list of objects, how you want to iterate over them, and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is too loop through 1 array and find the (assuming 1) element in the other array that match the current one:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $item) {
    $other = array_filter($array2, function ($item2) use ($item) { 
        return $item2->ServiceId == $item->ServiceId;
    });
    if (!empty($other)) {
        $item->StartTime = current($other)->SomethingElse;
    }
}
```

Because you're dealing with objects merging all properties is a bit tricky.

Here's an example:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15a9710dea77672c4ac4165044ad2c7aae4ae234